# progress bar of google speech-to-text api long_running_recognize operation

Tags: python, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767197/get-progress-of-a-long-running-recognize-operation-google-cloud-speech-api) one asked on SO but asking it again because the latest answer is more than a year old and the API has considerably changed. (I believe)

I am running a `long_running_recognize` operation and would like to know the progress of the same.

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types

gcs_uri = 'gs://my-new-videos/a49e0bf49a2e4d95b322bbf802e09d0e.wav'
client = speech.SpeechClient()

audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    language_code='en-US',
    audio_channel_count=2,
    enable_separate_recognition_per_channel=False,
    model='video',
    enable_word_time_offsets=False)

# ideally a way to get some sort of progress bar to know how long to wait.
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio) 
print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
response = operation.result(timeout=90)
```

Apparently one can run `operation.running()` and `operation.done()` to get the status of the `operation` but I am unable to figure out how to use it to tell me how long I'd have to wait or how much is already done. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your example but processing is not started until `response = operation.result(timeout=90)` is run and then it seems to block code execution. If, instead, we use a callback-approach, such as the one in [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/gapic/v1/api.html), we can access `Operation.metadata.progress_percent` while waiting for the operation to complete. As an example here I check the progress every 5s:

```py
import time

from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums


client = speech_v1.SpeechClient()

encoding = enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC
sample_rate_hertz = 16000
language_code = 'en-US'
config = {'encoding': encoding, 'sample_rate_hertz': sample_rate_hertz, 'language_code': language_code}
uri = 'gs://gcs-test-data/vr.flac'
audio = {'uri': uri}

response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

def callback(operation_future):
    result = operation_future.result()
    progress = response.metadata.progress_percent
    print(result)

response.add_done_callback(callback)

progress = 0

while progress < 100:
    try:
        progress = response.metadata.progress_percent
        print('Progress: {}%'.format(progress))
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Note that in this case I used a public audio file which is short and it goes from 0 to 100% but seems to work:

```py
Progress: 0%
...
Progress: 0%
results {
  alternatives {
    transcript: "it\'s okay so what am I doing here why am I here at GDC talking about VR video it\'s because I believe my favorite games I love games I believe in games my favorite games are the ones that are all about the stories I love narrative game design I love narrative-based games and I think that when it comes to telling stories in VR bring together capturing the world with narrative based games and narrative based game design is going to unlock some of the killer apps and killer stories of the medium"
    confidence: 0.959626555443
  }
}
results {
  alternatives {
    transcript: "so I\'m really here looking for people who are interested in telling us or two stories that are planning projects around telling those types of stories and I would love to talk to you so if this sounds like your project if you\'re looking at blending VR video and interactivity to tell a story I want to talk to you I want to help you so if this sounds like you please get in touch please come find me I\'ll be here all week I have pink hair I work for Google and I would love to talk with you further about VR video interactivity and storytelling"
    confidence: 0.954977035522
  }
}

Progress: 100%
```